# How to limit Administration menu to Admins, Mods and Owners (PyCharm 2020.3.3 Python 3.9.1

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py, python-3.9

I created an Administration cog a long time ago but I didn't limit it for administrators. I tried to limit it for admins but I was only able to limit the cog a single role. How do I make it that the cog is limited to people who have Admin powers?

Current Code:

```
    async def cog_check(self, ctx):
        admin = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Admin")
        return admin in ctx.author.roles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [discord.ext.commands.has_permissions()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_permissions#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions) if you need that the person executing the command has a certain permission, otherwise you an also use [permissions_for()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=permissions_in#discord.abc.GuildChannel.permissions_for) that return a [Permissions object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=permissions_in#discord.Permissions) and use the [permission administrator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=permissions_in#discord.Permissions.administrator)

It would look like this

```
async def cog_check(self, ctx):
    return ctx.channel.permissions_for(ctx.author).administrator
```

this coroutine will return True if and only if the member has the permission administrator (in one of his roles or if he was specified the permission in a channel)